# How can I get Start-Class programmatically?

Tags: spring-boot

How can I get Start-Class manifest property programmatically from a code in a jar inside BOOT-INF/lib?

I know I can get the LaunchURLClassLoader, call getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") and then look for the property in the MANIFEST.MF but I'm not sure this is the best aproach

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine and will probably work, but you can go one level of abstraction higher and use the Spring's [Resource Loader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader).

```
Resource template = ctx.getResource("classpath:/path/to/manifest");
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to spring context

Comment: The ResourceLoader will work with the correct classLoader and will get any resource that is available on the classpath (including inside jars). As I said - your approach is fine, but the ResourceLoader in this case will take care of getting the correct classLoader. Have you tested the code to see if it works? If it works (your version on ResourceLoader version - doesn't matter) - then you don't have a problem and you can move on.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserAgentSpringBootApplicationNameDiscoverer {

    protected static final String BOOT_INF_DIR = "BOOT-INF/";

    protected static final String MANIFEST_DIR = "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";

    public String getStartClassFromClassLoader(ClassLoader cl) {

        URL bootInfUrl = cl.getResource(BOOT_INF_DIR);
        if (bootInfUrl == null || "".equals(bootInfUrl.toString().trim())) {
            return null;
        }

        String rootMetaInfUrl = bootInfUrl.toString().replace(BOOT_INF_DIR, MANIFEST_DIR);
        InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream(rootMetaInfUrl.toString());
        if (is == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Manifest manifest = null;

        try {
            manifest = new Manifest(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Start-Class");

    }
}
```